# How to convert seconds to java.sql.Timestamp?

Tags: java, timestamp

I needed to truncate milliseconds to seconds and implemented it in this way:

```
private static Long millisToSeconds(Long millisValue) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisValue);
}
```

So now it truncates millis as expected, for example:

```
Long secondsValue = millisToSeconds(1554052265830L);
System.out.println("millisToSeconds ---> " + toSeconds); 
// Prints millisToSeconds ---> 1554052265
```

But then I want to convert `secondsValue` to `java.sql.Timestamp` but the following implementation results in an error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

What should I fix in my implementation to convert seconds to timestamp so that the resulting timestamp looks like `2019-03-31 11:45:06` ?

Comment: `...but the following implementation results in...` which implementation? I think you're missing some code.

Comment: According to [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) there is a `Timestamp(long time)` constructor which `Constructs a Timestamp object using a milliseconds time value.` so all you need to do is to multiply `secondsValue` by 1000

Comment: Without your code it’s very hard to tell how to fix it. Could you please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on your database datatype and the capabilities of your JDBC driver use either `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` or `LocalDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Tip: use primitive `long` (lowercase `l`)  instead of `Long` objects.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I am assuming that you are asking for a `java.sql.Timestamp` for use with your SQL database. In most cases you shouldn’t ask for that. The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated, and a modern JDBC driver or JPA implementation will be happy to accept a type from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

```
    long millisValue = 1_554_052_265_830L;
    Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisValue);
    i = i.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(i);
```

> 2019-03-31T17:11:05Z

I don’t know why you wanted to truncate to seconds, but you can see that it has been done (or it’s easy to leave that line out).

Some JDBC drivers accept an `Instant` directly when you pass it to `PreparedStatement.setObject` (one of the overloaded versions of that method) even though the JDBC specification doesn’t require this. If yours doesn’t, use an `OffsetDateTime` instead. Convert like this:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = i.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

> 2019-03-31T17:11:05Z

You can see that the value is still the same, only the type is different.

> What should I fix in my implementation to convert seconds to timestamp
>   so that the resulting timestamp looks like `2019-03-31 11:45:06` ?

First, as I said, you should fix your code not to require a `Timestamp`, but also you are asking the impossible. As far as I know, `Timestamp.toString` would always produce at least one decimal on the seconds, so it would at least look like `2019-03-31 11:45:06.0`.

If you *do* indispensably need a `Timestamp` for a legacy API that you cannot or don’t want to change just now, convert the `Instant` from before:

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(i);
    System.out.println(ts);
```

> 2019-03-31 19:11:05.0

Don’t be fooled by the time looking different (19:11 instead of 17:11). `Timestamp` prints in my local time zone, which is Europe/Copenhagen, 2 hours ahead of UTC since summer time (DST) began on March 31. So we have still got the same point in time.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`to format the date as per your requirement. See below

```
    Long secondsValue = millisToSeconds(1554052265830L);
    System.out.println("millisToSeconds ---> " + secondsValue);
    Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(secondsValue);
    String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").format(timeStamp.getTime());
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: If the point is to obtain a string, then one should use `java.util.Date` (or better: one of the `java.time` classes and not `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Assuming a `Timestamp` was asked for for use with an SQL database, one shouldn’t use a string instead. BTW your code is wrong. I got `1970-40-19 12:40:52`, there’s no way this could be right.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that you are using `Timestamp.valueOf(String)` (possibly with `secondsValue.toString()` as the argument?).

A `java.sql.Timestamp` is a special version of `java.util.Date` with nanosecond precision to serialize/deserialize SQL `TIMESTAMP` values. It is not a second value at all.

The [constructor of `Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp-long-) take a millisecond value, not a second value (for nanosecond precision, you need to use the separate `setNanos` with the sub-second nanoseconds).

In any case the proper way would be to use:

```
long milliseconds = ...; 
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds);
long truncatedMilliseconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds);
// or truncatedMilliseconds = (milliseconds / 1000) * 1000;
Timestamp value = new Timestamp(truncatedMilliseconds);
```

However, since you are talking about needing a specific string format, I'm not sure you need this at all. Unless you are using JDBC to store this value in a database, you should not be using `java.sql.Timestamp` at all (and even when using JDBC, then it would probably be better to use `java.time.LocalDatetime` instead).